# Migration options for scheduler service running in quartz

Tags: spring, spring-integration, quartz-scheduler

We have a scheduling service running in weblogic server, implemented using Quartz API and custom db tables to manage create, delete, suspend and resume tasks on configuration of jobs and various pollers (database, jms) with the help of UI framework in Angular JS. Now we decided to go with open source and trying to make use of the capabilities of spring integration.

But with spring integration, any idea how one can dynamically perform create, suspend and resume tasks on a database and JMS pollers? Or can we integrate Quartz with Spring Integration and make use of capabilities of both?

Thanks

Comment: see http://www.baeldung.com/spring-quartz-schedule. Spring can be configured to use the existing quartz database config to execute the jobs on the same schedule. You'll need to make sure your poller task will run in your spring context.

Comment: There is no direct Quartz support in Spring Integration yet: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2731. But yes, you can achieve some solution via `QuartzJobBean` solution.